# Is an open port for VPN protected from hackers?

Tags: networking, vpn, security, openvpn

I'm trying to implement a VPN.
I read about configuring VPN servers on Windows (built-in), and also several 3d party software like OpenVPN etc. But all these require a port to be opened in the router for VPN in order to work - but opening a port could expose the server to hackers.
So does VPN itself have protection for this open port, or even with VPN the server can be hacked?
What is the solution?

Comment: You post more new questions by fail to follow up on numerous answers we have posted for you.

Comment: @John This is a concret question and i think requires a simple answer. I follow the suggestion by you on other question , so i made a concret question.

Comment: But the questions remain open and you do not follow up.

Comment: @John You seggested to the other question that the Question how to  create a vpn is to complex to answer.So i made research , and now i have a question for vpn security only.

Comment: any open port has the potential to be a security issue, if not now, then maybe in the future as so called "hackers" find new ways to exploit existing systems. VPN's do have security in place, but the security, much like a chain, is as strong as its weakest link

Comment: @JaromandaX  Properly done security is NOT as strong as the weakest link.   It is built of layers.   If you have an account with 2 FA on it and a weak password, the password is the weakest link, but does not provide access without the second FA also being compromised.

Comment: @davidgo But if you then leave your account logged in at the library…

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That makes little sense.  If you are using a public access computer you should definately not put a VPN on it (and should be prevented from doing so anyway on a publicly accessible computer that has been competently set up).  Even if you did though, all a VPN does is create a virtual connection between 2 points - whatever services you were trying to access should still be protected with their own access.

Comment: @davidgo Point is, security _is_ only as strong as the weakest link. You can reinforce _one_ of those links, sure, but it's little use getting an unpickable door lock if your door is made of wood, or your windows are made of untoughened glass.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Disagree.   Per my answer to JaromandaX good security is built up of Layers.   Your Windows can be made of regular glass without significantly increasing your risk if they are 100 meters in the air and/or the property is surrounded by a moat and/or you have guards on-site/and/or you have burglar unbreakable burglar bars... If you have more then 1 of the mitigations I listed all the better - more layers.

Comment: @davidgo So I bribe a guard to lower the drawbridge and let me in. And yes, you can add more layers to _that_ link by requiring a consensus of eleven guards for every action – in which case, I'll get a [rubber bodysuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo) and [psychic paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_items#Psychic_paper) and blag my way in. This [isn't a controversial idea](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1193216) – the fact 2FA exists doesn't mean it can't still be bypassed in many cases.

Comment: Your question seems to be about the security of a specific VPN server (since you'll be opening a port that ultimately leads to that server software), but you fail to specify exactly which software you'll be using. Any vulnerabilities that do exist would likely be "zero day" exploits anyway since VPN servers wouldn't intentionally have vulnerabilities. I don't really think this would be a very good question, even if the specific VPN software had been specified. At the end of the day, hackers will be exploiting the VPN server software, not the port.

Comment: @wizzwizz5 At least post a readable limk to the "it isnt controversial" link - eg https://informationsecurity.report/Resources/Whitepapers/7f28ebd7-7068-4c34-9655-2e182f86c463_TheWeakestLinkRevisited.pdf - which ifrom my reading is totally irrelevant to my point.

Comment: By analogy, opening a port is like cutting open a hole in the wall. Is that insecure? Not necessarily, perhaps you fill the whole with a sturdy door. Or if you want some people to come in, perhaps the opening is a store show room for customers, where they can interact wit the products you set out for them. There would then be further security mechanisms that prevent customers (who are allowed into the main area) from wander into the staff-only back office.

Answer (score 33):

> The server need an open port , so this port can be in danger. Even if i choose Wireguard or open vpn , i think they need an open port

Ports are not "in danger". One cannot attack ports. One only attacks *services* running on those ports. (Much like you can call a phone number but you aren't *talking to* a phone number, you're talking to a person behind it, and it's the same person whether they have one phone number or five.)

So if you want a service to be accessible from outside, that *unavoidably* means it'll be attackable from outside, regardless of "ports".

The way you deal with this problem is by carefully selecting *which* services to expose, as it's the services where the vulnerabilities are; the number of ports is irrelevant.

Most VPN servers are already hardened against attacks – its kind of their *whole purpose* to be exposed to the public – but you can rank them e.g. by popularity, historic CVE count, etc. Generally speaking, OpenVPN and WireGuard are both okay.

Comment: A TL;DR at the top emphasizing that VPN software are generally designed against attacks would be good. Most readers would be satisfied with this conclusion. Maybe putting the first sentence of the last paragraph in bold text suffices.

Comment: @iBug: So that we don't bother people who want to quickly set up VPNs with boring IT security knowledge? I don't know... that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Heinzi Chances are such people wouldn't bother as well. My point is, the last paragraph answers *the* question in the title, so putting *the* answer at the most noticeable place is a better approach.

Comment: @iBug: No, I specifically don't _want_ to just answer the question in the title. It seems to me that the entire question post rests on a fundamental lack of understanding about what "open ports" do; it would be a disservice to OP to just answer it literally and let them carry on.

Comment: Sorry friends. I don't pretend to have greater knownledge than you. If i do , I would not posted the question. One time we get hacked from an open port , so i just wanted to know if the open port for VPN have any risque or is secure. You that have good knowledge in security ,can just respond that . And as you can see , this question is viewed 4k times in few days , so i think other people are interested to know the answer.

Comment: This is an article about why vpn with open ports are easy target. But also exists Vpn services that does not require open ports. https://www.remote.it/resources/hacker-groups-are-exploiting-cves-to-break-into-vpns-how-to-close-your-open-ports-while-maintaining-access-for-users

Comment: @alex interesting read - but note that none of the VPN's listed are OpenVPN or Wireguard (which differ because they are open source and have been externally audited)  Also, the vulnerabilities in those clients are at least 4 years old.  Also note that compromising the VPN does not mean that your system is compromised - only that someone can get access to your internal network.   If you are worried about people hacking your VPN, I'd suggest use Wireguard as it is the simplest major VPN implementation - which means less chance of backdoors).  Also make sure you keep it up to date.

Comment: @alex - also, The above article is misleading.  VPN's are not "easy targets".  VPN's with known vulnerabilities are easy targets - and in the case of commercial offerings like the ones in the article - they are also juicy ones - IE its a large (and if hacked, likely with an incompetent IT department)  corporation which means the reward for hacking is likely greater.    It is certainly still more secure to run a VPN then not if you need to make your database remotely accessible.

Comment: @alex It's technically not possible to have a VPN setup without using an "open port" - even if you're using something like reverse port forwarding you're still using an open port -- not using an open port effectively means not being connected to a network (like the internet), which makes the very function of a VPN useless.

Answer (score 11):

I think you may misunderstand the security model provided by VPN's.

My first comment is that many VPN clients DON'T require a port to be open (Servers arguably do), and that an open port in and of itself does not make the system vulnerable - any vulnerability will come down to what can be done through the open port.

**Provided the VPN implementation is robust** the only advantage an open port gives to an adversary is the knowledge that there is some kind of device offering some kind of service (and probably indications of the kind of VPN running on it).  Thats it.  It does not give any kind of foothold into the system at all.

If you are running a VPN server and are concerned about this there are a few ways you can mitigate even the above issue.  Look at "Port Knocking", which can be a way to keep the port closed until a hidden series of packets are received by the router (and the router does not need to respond to these).   You can also limit the IP's/ranges that can connect to the VPN which can significantly cut down on the likelyhood of the VPN server being probed.  In a similar vein, you could always run a web server and require a specific  URL on a different system - possibly on a different network - to be hit which could then be trusted to send an instruction to open up the VPN port to the appropriate IP address.

Another approach might be to spin up a basic server/VPS (eg AWS EC2 instance), and have your VPN "servers" all connect as clients to that  instance.  In that way the actual VPN endpoints are not directly reachable except throuh the VPN server - which can be locked down as above.

Another thing to consider is the choice of VPN protocol.  Wireguard is very small and lightweight, and has been well audited for security, so it may be a good choice.

If you prefer security through obscurity, you may want to consider OpenVPN running on port 443 shared with a real web server (eg https://serverfault.com/questions/187915/openvpn-port-share-with-apache-ssl).

Comment: ok , but let's say that we have a limited budget , and we can implement a vpn server on a Windows Pc ( built in ) without 3d party software , and have some other vpn clients. The server need an open port , so this port can be in danger. Even if i choose Wireguard or open vpn , i think they need an open port. So the problem is the server that can be attacked ( not the clients ). and if we have a database on that server this can be in danger. or maybe if we move database to another Pc. ???

Comment: @alex - You can’t implement a VPN server within Windows without third-party software like OpenVPN. Wire guard is also third-party software.

Comment: If you want to provide any kind of a service, for example, VPN, be prepared that there **will** be attempts to break in using that service. This is why we tend to "close unused ports" — to not to worry much about services that were started by accident. "Open port" itself poses no risk — all the risk is with the software listening to it. This is why the answer mentions the VPN software needs to be *robust*, e.g. at least, have no known vulnerabilities. Also you need to use good security practices (e.g. secure passwords and so on). And monitor the usage, detect and block break in attempts.

Comment: You might be able to set up VPN access through Windows without third party software - I would not know for sure - , but its probably not a great idea.  If you do (and I recommend against it) - steer clear of PPTP and L2TP as those protocols are broken.  Except in niche cases, VPNs belong on routers, not PC's - and definitely not PC's acting as data servers.

Comment: @Ramhound This article speak about creating VPN server on windows 10 without 3d party software : https://pureinfotech.com/setup-vpn-server-windows-10/ . and also there's a method for vpn client. But i don't know how secure is this idea.

Comment: So implement that solution. I certainly trust OpenVPN over that particular solution

Comment: @alex it would be foolish to set up that vpn. PPP whivh underlies The PPTP protocol contemplated in the link you provided is the least secure protocol for vpn in common use.  You are better off using pretty much anything else.  Just reading the iverview and security sections of the Wikipedia page at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol should tell you just how bad it is.

Comment: @alex What kind of router is the connection behind? A router is a much mire ligical place to add a vpn - and many routers support acting as von servers.

Comment: @davidgo But when making a VPN connection on Windows 10, there are other protocols in the list not only PPTP . List of Protocols : : Automatic , PPTP , L2TP IPSEC with certificate , L2TP IPSEC WITH PRE-SHARED KEY , SSTP , IKEV2.  So you think all these are bad ? So Why Microsoft implement this built in VPN on their Windows System ?

Comment: No, not all these protocols are bad.  PPTP is.  I've not done too much with IPSEC but its stood the test of time reasonably well. Its complex to set up.  I've not looked into SSTP or IKEV2.  While looking into it the following line at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol jumped out at me - SSTP is intended only for remote client access, it generally does not support site-to-site VPN tunnels - This tells me its not a proper VPN protocol, and then the question is "Why use a VPN at all, just use remote access"...

Comment: @davidgo On windows 10 , if you go to Settings-Network and Internet - VPN-ADD VPN Conection  , in VPN Type you can see these all the protocols mentioned on my previous message , and SSTP is on the list.

Comment: @alex Yes.  Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @alex I have a feeling you misunderstand the purpose of VPNs and the typical threat model. Normally, you have a single hardened entry point (gateway), and the entire infrastructure hidden behind it, at least somewhat protected (i.e. no root access, sensible passwords etc.). Even with a limited budget, fully on-prem, your infra machines and the production DB should be separated, and the production DB never directly exposed to the Internet. Your description made me worry it currently is, and if that's the case, VPN is the least of your concerns right now.

Comment: @Lodinn one of reason making this question was the security of a Database inside a vpn  configuration. Because we faced a hacker attack when used just port forward to access a remote database. So we thought using a VPN configuration. But even on VPN , port forward is needed. So should i worry about security of database on this case , i mean using this port that is open for VPN has the risque to be hacked again ? We have a low budget , so we need to keep the database inside the computer that is VPN server. So is there a risque that database can be hacked again even with vpn ?

Comment: @alex Your comments to Lodinn show that this is an XY problem - You should focus on the threat you are trying mitigate rather then an open port for a VPN.  In the context of your above comment you can forget about the security risk of an open port for a VPN it is insignificant compared to your wider problems.   You should look at a VPN as a way of narrowing down who can get access to your network - and OpenVPN or Wireguard will do this for you.   The idea of a VPN here is that the VPN needs to be hacked before the hacker can get to the database....

Comment: That said, if the database was exposed directly to the wider internet (at minimum without limitingit to specific IPs) whoever set that up should be removed from an IT role for gross incompetence - they would have had to take specific steps to make it that insecure.  If they did not directly expose the database it is much more likely that the database was compromised through an SQL injection attack through the front end of the website - this is one of the most common ways of being hacked, and securing the database will do nothing to solve the problem as the database trusts the web server.

Comment: @alex It is as I thought. No, VPN would provide you with better security. Databases are extremely feature-rich and thus have a huge attack surface. They are not meant to be deployed with direct access from the Internet. The rest depends on your application. Highly sensitive data may be completely on-prem and airgapped, don't provide remote access at it at all. If you do, you likely have at least SSH access, that could be attacked. Between RDP and OpenVPN, I'd say OpenVPN is safer and achieves a good balance between usability and security.

Comment: Regarding budget - you may have everything on a single PC/VM and configure your database server to not accept non-local connections. Recent advertisement of VPNs for concealing one's online identity have distorted the perception of VPN as a technology, but this is what it was conceived for in the first place - providing a way for engineers to work remotely and safely with company's data. If this is an internal database, all authorized workers will have to VPN to your local subnet first to access it. If you serve it over the web, software engineers have to be competent to prevent SQL attacks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in everything security related, you should start assuming everything CAN be hacked. And, if exposed on the internet, your service WILL be probed every day. This isn't meant to be scary: it is just what you see as soon as you put something online. You're goal is to minimize the risks...

The first choice I think you need to make is: who will manage this service? It could be you, but this is not the only option. Anyway, if your hosts's security is worth something you should ask yourself if you can really do it by yourself or trust a professional/service.

Back to the "ports"... There is nothing wrong with an open port: it is just the way the service "listens" to requests. You need to focus on using a secure software (ie. [openvpn](https://openvpn.net)) configured in the right way.

Additionally some VPNs do not even need a port to be opened because they relay the data between hosts. An example of such service is [zerotier](https://www.zerotier.com).

I hope this helps you to choose wisely and, probably, do not run your first VPN service in production by yourself.

Comment: Maybe we should use VPN service that does not use open ports : https://www.remote.it/resources/hacker-groups-are-exploiting-cves-to-break-into-vpns-how-to-close-your-open-ports-while-maintaining-access-for-users

Comment: I use zerotier because it gives to me a kind of LAN across the internet for some services I need to use, but I didn't choose it because of the closed ports. To be honest you can use it with or without allowing the incoming traffic.
The main difference is in the route your traffic takes: if you open the doors the vpn clients could talk directly, otherwise some other server needs to relay the traffic increasing latency.